# Editing on a question with the "Answer This Question" button breaks the editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, inline-editor

This is peanuts, still you might want to know.

If you edit an answer on a question which misses the inlined answer box but has instead the "Answer This Question" button, the answer editor is broken.

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to the [SandBox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)
- Hit `Edit` on any answer
- Cancel the edit
- Hit `Answer this Question`
- ???
- Profit!

Screenshot:

[image: Freehandcircles outlining the issue.]

Comment: Note: This is only for inline editing - for <2k rep, it performs as normal.

Comment: If I follow the reported steps, I don't see anything strange. I see the dialog box saying there are already 30 answers, but that is not something strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the "Answer this question" button is shown instead of the actual editor, the initialization of the editor JavaScript is delayed until the button is clicked. This "delaying" happens by means of a callback that is stowed away until the click.

However, this callback was overwritten by a no-op at the moment you started *another* editor, hence by the time you clicked the button, "nothing happens" was the plan.

Nice catch, thanks. Fixed in the next build.